# Could the Vorlons be responsible for every race having invented Swedish meatballs?

Tags: babylon-5

In the episode “Walkabout”, G’Kar reveals than the Narn food “breen” is the same as Swedish meatballs from Earth, and that all sentient races have them.

> It's an Earth food. They are called Swedish meatballs. It's a strange thing, but every sentient race has its own version of these Swedish meatballs! I suspect it's one of those great universal mysteries which will either never be explained, or which would drive you mad if you ever learned the truth.

The obvious answer to me is that this was from the Vorlons, given that they gave most every race telepaths, and apparently a belief that religious figures match them.

Could the Vorlons imparting their culinary preferences on younger races be the reason every sentient race has Swedish meatballs?

Comment: Possibly an oblique reference to Douglas Adams who said the same about gin and tonic (jynnan tonyx, etc)?

Comment: Meat in a ball? Hardly the most original of ideas

Comment: Probably the shadows, as they're the "what do you want" type, not "who are you" Vorlons. Are you a meatball, or do you want meatballs?

Comment: @Valorum "The smell, the taste!" There's more to the meatball than the meat. The spices and such are part of it too.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I always thought so. Regarding the question itself, there's no reason to pick the Vorlons as a possible cause for this over any of the First Ones. Any one of them could have had a strange sense of humor and caused this to happen. Really, the Vorlons seem to humorless it's almost an argument against it being them.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Is there evidence that races other than Vorlons manipulated humans? I agree, it does see a bit out of character for them to seed this preferred taste.

Comment: I love this question. No way to answer it, of course, but connects the dots in a very satisfying way.

Comment: @MikeC I was kind of hoping that JMS had said something about it when he was active on Usenet or whatever, given how involved he was with fans back in the day. Still, I would accept a “we don’t know for sure; here’s evidence that would support/refute it” answer if that’s the best we can do.

Comment: Given the proximity to Norway, I blame Asgard.

Comment: Unless it's somehow related to a race developing telepathy, I doubt the Vorlons would bother.

Comment: There is a Narn food called “breen”? There is a race in the Star Trek universe called the Breen. Just saying!